# Django Models: Setting up daily time slots

Tags: django, django-models

I’ve been thinking about this for a while, and not getting anywhere.

Using Django, I’m trying to set up a time slot reservation web app, but I’m getting hung up on how to set up the models.

Essentially, every day of the week would have time slots offered like: 09:00, 09:10, 09:20, 09:30, 09:40, etc. And each of those time slots would include the specified time, date, and count of people.

**My first try...**
I was initially thinking I’d make records for every time slot, for every day of the week; then I could query that to display available time slots on the website. That seems really inefficient though, because I’d have to create around 70 entries for each day of the week.

**My Second Try...**
Then I was thinking I’d just lay out all of the time slots on the website itself, then when someone reserves one of the slots, save that to the database. However, doing that, I’m not sure how I would then NOT display that time slot on the site.

I included a rough mockup below to describe what I'm trying to accomplish.

Any ideas that would lead me the right direction would be great. Thanks!

[Time Slot Reservations Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEQVg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using .objects.bulk_create([]) to batch add records for each time slot.

Answer (score 0):

NOT SURE IF THIS IS GOOD IDEA BUT

A long time ago, when I was creating similar app. I stored a JSON object in model

```
{
    "schedule_day": [
        {
            "start": 8,
            "end": 16
        }
    ]
}
```

and when someone would make an appointment (let's say for 10am-11am) i would edit a json like this

```
{
    "schedule_day": [
        {
            "start": 8,
            "end": 10
        },
        {
            "start": 11,
            "end": 16
        }
    ]
}
```

I remember that it was pain in the ass to make it work, but at the end of the day it worked fine. Back then i couldn't figured out how to store not full hours but I guess if you would store everything in minutes it would work well.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just going my first route by creating individual records for each time slot.

Using .objects.bulk_create([]) made it pretty easy.